# cant change airflow db files location

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I'm tring to set the `airflow` in a directory that is not the default directory (`~ / airflow`), but it doesn't work:

```
export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/PycharmProjects/airflow_example/airflow
airflow db init
```

Result:
airflow folder created under `~ / airflow`

How can I change the airflow folder (database and configurations) ?